# How to make data model of this api?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http

I want to make a data model for my **cartList api**. if you hit following api in your browser 5 product will be added to your cart.

**https://www.moharaj.com.bd/_public/addToCart?quantity=5&slug=cotton-fleece-hoodie-for-men-tekka-8486&variant_id=$variant_id=24469**

you can check your cart list through this api:

**https://www.moharaj.com.bd/_public/cartToContent**

But my problem is when I try to make a model of this **cartToContent** that means cart list api there always generate a unique row Id or token which I can't store. can anyone has any idea how to make a data model of this api?? I have made a data model. I have given below:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final cartToContentModel = cartToContentModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

CartToContentModel cartToContentModelFromJson(String str) => CartToContentModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String cartToContentModelToJson(CartToContentModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CartToContentModel {
    CartToContentModel({
        required this.cartTotal,
        required this.cartContent,
        required this.itemCount,
    });

    String cartTotal;
    CartContent cartContent;
    int itemCount;

    factory CartToContentModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartToContentModel(
        cartTotal: json["cart_total"],
        cartContent: CartContent.fromJson(json["cart_content"]),
        itemCount: json["item_count"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "cart_total": cartTotal,
        "cart_content": cartContent.toJson(),
        "item_count": itemCount,
    };
}

class CartContent {
    CartContent({
        required this.c827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167,
    });

    C827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167 c827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167;

    factory CartContent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartContent(
        c827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167: C827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167.fromJson(json["c827cdf7ba8f3127f293690569aff167"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "c827cdf7ba8f3127f293690569aff167": c827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167.toJson(),
    };
}

class C827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167 {
    C827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167({
        required this.rowId,
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.qty,
        required this.price,
        required this.weight,
        required this.options,
        required this.discount,
        required this.tax,
        required this.subtotal,
    });

    String rowId;
    int id;
    String name;
    String qty;
    int price;
    int weight;
    Options options;
    int discount;
    int tax;
    int subtotal;

    factory C827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => C827Cdf7Ba8F3127F293690569Aff167(
        rowId: json["rowId"],
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        qty: json["qty"],
        price: json["price"],
        weight: json["weight"],
        options: Options.fromJson(json["options"]),
        discount: json["discount"],
        tax: json["tax"],
        subtotal: json["subtotal"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "rowId": rowId,
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "qty": qty,
        "price": price,
        "weight": weight,
        "options": options.toJson(),
        "discount": discount,
        "tax": tax,
        "subtotal": subtotal,
    };
}

class Options {
    Options({
        required this.attributeId,
        required this.variantId,
        required this.image,
    });

    dynamic attributeId;
    String variantId;
    List<Image> image;

    factory Options.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Options(
        attributeId: json["attribute_id"],
        variantId: json["variant_id"],
        image: List<Image>.from(json["image"].map((x) => Image.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "attribute_id": attributeId,
        "variant_id": variantId,
        "image": List<dynamic>.from(image.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Image {
    Image({
        required this.id,
        required this.productId,
        required this.productImage,
        required this.createdAt,
        required this.prefixUrl,
        required this.updatedAt,
    });

    int id;
    int productId;
    String productImage;
    DateTime createdAt;
    String prefixUrl;
    DateTime updatedAt;

    factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Image(
        id: json["id"],
        productId: json["product_id"],
        productImage: json["product_image"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        prefixUrl: json["prefix_url"],
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "product_id": productId,
        "product_image": productImage,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "prefix_url": prefixUrl,
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `map` of `cartitems values` to `list` of cartitems.

Here's the updated model.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final cartToContentModel = cartToContentModelFromMap(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

class CartToContentModel {
    CartToContentModel({
        this.cartTotal,
        this.cartContent,
        this.itemCount,
    });

    final String cartTotal;
    final List<CartContent> cartContent;
    final int itemCount;

    factory CartToContentModel.fromJson(String str) => CartToContentModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory CartToContentModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartToContentModel(
        cartTotal: json["cart_total"],
        cartContent: List<CartContent>.from(json["cart_content"].values.map((item) => CartContent.fromMap(item))),
        itemCount: json["item_count"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "cart_total": cartTotal,
        "cart_content": List<dynamic>.from(cartContent.map((x) => x.toMap())),
        "item_count": itemCount,
    };
}

class CartContent {
    CartContent({
        this.rowId,
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.qty,
        this.price,
        this.weight,
        this.options,
        this.discount,
        this.tax,
        this.subtotal,
    });

    final String rowId;
    final int id;
    final String name;
    final String qty;
    final int price;
    final int weight;
    final Options options;
    final int discount;
    final int tax;
    final int subtotal;

    factory CartContent.fromJson(String str) => CartContent.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory CartContent.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartContent(
        rowId: json["rowId"],
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        qty: json["qty"],
        price: json["price"],
        weight: json["weight"],
        options: Options.fromMap(json["options"]),
        discount: json["discount"],
        tax: json["tax"],
        subtotal: json["subtotal"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "rowId": rowId,
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "qty": qty,
        "price": price,
        "weight": weight,
        "options": options.toMap(),
        "discount": discount,
        "tax": tax,
        "subtotal": subtotal,
    };
}

class Options {
    Options({
        this.attributeId,
        this.variantId,
        this.image,
    });

    final dynamic attributeId;
    final String variantId;
    final List<Image> image;

    factory Options.fromJson(String str) => Options.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Options.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Options(
        attributeId: json["attribute_id"],
        variantId: json["variant_id"],
        image: List<Image>.from(json["image"].map((x) => Image.fromMap(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "attribute_id": attributeId,
        "variant_id": variantId,
        "image": List<dynamic>.from(image.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    };
}

class Image {
    Image({
        this.id,
        this.productId,
        this.productImage,
        this.createdAt,
        this.prefixUrl,
        this.updatedAt,
    });

    final int id;
    final int productId;
    final String productImage;
    final DateTime createdAt;
    final String prefixUrl;
    final DateTime updatedAt;

    factory Image.fromJson(String str) => Image.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Image.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Image(
        id: json["id"],
        productId: json["product_id"],
        productImage: json["product_image"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        prefixUrl: json["prefix_url"],
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "product_id": productId,
        "product_image": productImage,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "prefix_url": prefixUrl,
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

Comment: okay thats okay but the problem is when I try to call the **CartToContent** api after **addToCart** api I got cart list in postman. But when I call it in my apps it returns null or empty cart.

Comment: In postman when I auto generate code there has a header called **Cookies** and the value of coocies is **XSR TOken** and **laravel session**